# Serialize object into python code instead of pickle

Tags: python, serialization

In python (3.6) I am using SimpleNameSpace (could easily be converted to class) to store parameters for different model runs.  Most are dynamically created, but some are manually created or modified. I need to keep track of the parameters used. I know this can easily be done with pickle - but this makes it impossible (or at least cumbersome) to manually edit or create new parameter files.

I would like to be about to save each SimpleNameSpace as a separate.py file which can be later be imported.

I could create a string for the SimpleNameSpace definition and write it out to a .py file, but this seems very convoluted and error prone.

pseudocode follows:

```
paramRun1 = SimpleNameSpace(
  param1 = ...
  param2 = ...
...
)
```

I would like to write out the above code to paramRun1.py

and then be able to use it in other code as

```
from paramRun1 import paramRun1
p1 = paramRun1.param1
...
```

Thank you for your help,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `namedtuple`.

```
# paramRun1.py
from collections import namedtuple


paramRun1 = namedtuple("paramRun1", ["param1",  "param2"])
pr1 = paramRun1(1, 2)

# a more practical example
Student = namedtuple("Student", ["name", "age"])
Tom = Student("Tom", 18)
```

And use it like this:

```sh
>>> import paramRun1
>>> p1 = paramRun1.pr1.param1
>>> p1
1
>>> print(f"my name is {paramRun1.Tom.name}, I'm {paramRun1.Tom.age} old")
my name is Tom, I'm 18 old
```

I retrieved the official document, it presented as follows:

> SimpleNamespace may be useful as a replacement for `class NS: pass`. However, for a structured record type use namedtuple() instead.

So in your case do you have to use SimpleNamespace?

Comment: I agree, I could use a named tuple as well - however, the problem is that I want to serialize it so that it can be imported as a .py file - however, SimpleNameSpace has the benefit that it is mutable